# Problema com each jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou recebendo via `JSON` um `array`, percorro ele com o `.each()` do `JQUERY`, assim monto minha html, e a coloco em uma `div` dentro de minha página. Dito tudo isto e feito isto:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/produtos', function(data) {
        $('#todosProdutos').html('');
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
            var ANTIGO = $('#todosProdutos').html();

            var html = ANTIGO + '<div class="item">'
                    +'<div class="product">'
                    +'<div class="flip-container">'
                    +'<div class="flipper">'
                    +'<div class="front">'
                    +'<a href="detail">'
                    +'<img src="img/product1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">'
                    +'</a>'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'<div class="back">'
                    +'<a href="detail">'
                    +'<img src="img/product1_2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">'
                    +'</a>'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'<a href="detail" class="invisible">'
                    +'<img src="img/product1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">'
                    +'</a>'
                    +'<div class="text">'
                    +'<h3><a href="detail">Fur coat with very but very very long name</a></h3>'
                    +'<p class="price">$143.00</p>'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'<!-- /.text -->'
                    +'</div>'
                    +'<!-- /.product -->'
                    +'</div>';
        });
        console.log(html);
        $('#todosProdutos').html(html);
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Quando dei o `console.log(html)` fala que a váriavel não esta definidade, isto sei o problema, é devido ao escopo de variavel, porém tentei colocar o `.html()` dentro do `.each()` e também não tive sucesso, aparece meu html, porém não coloca na página.

Onde pode estar meu erro ? E Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isto ?

Meu `console.log(data)`:

[image: console.log(data)]
[image: div com apenas um produto]
[image: meu array data]

Comment: Então @RenanRodrigues, está chegando valores de data que são 4 itens dentro do `array` e o `html` tem valores? na página não aparece pelo menos o html com as informações fixas que você colocou?

Comment: O que acontece e que estou fazendo um teste para saber se ele vai colocar os itens na tela, com valores fixo, sei que está chegando os dados corretamente agora o problema é na tela.

Comment: não sei bem, fiz uma edição, seu html estava errado! dá uma olhada ve se aparece como você mesmo disse 4 itens fixos (porque ela vai rodar 4 vezes se estiver certo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um simples ajuste:

No `$.each` não é só `data` é `data.produtos` pela forma de envio, então,

```
$.each(data.produtos ...
```

Segue ***código completo***:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/produtos', function(data) {
        $('#todosProdutos').html('');
        var html = "";
        $.each(data.produtos, function (key, item) 
        {
            html = html + '<div class="item">';
            html = html + '<div class="product">';
            html = html + '<div class="flip-container">';
            html = html + '<div class="flipper">';
            html = html + '<div class="front">';
            html = html + '<a href="detail">';
            html = html + '<img src="img/product1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
            html = html + '</a>';
            html = html + '</div>';
            html = html + '<div class="back">';
            html = html + '<a href="detail">';
            html = html + '<img src="img/product1_2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
            html = html + '</a>';
            html = html + '</div>';
            html = html + '</div>';
            html = html + '</div>';
            html = html + '<a href="detail" class="invisible">';
            html = html + '<img src="img/product1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
            html = html + '</a>';
            html = html + '<div class="text">';
            html = html + '<h3><a href="detail">Fur coat with very but very very long name</a></h3>';
            html = html + '<p class="price">$143.00</p>';
            html = html + '</div>';
            html = html + '</div>';                    
            html = html + '</div>';
        });
        console.log(html);
        $('#todosProdutos').html(html);
        console.log(data);
});
```

Me parece que seu código de valores (item) não está sendo colocado, mas, o problema relatado com esse simples ajuste vai funcionar.

Comment: Irmao realmente ainda não está colocando o html na página

Comment: Tem que ver se realmente está chegando alto em `data`  está chegando algo? tem como colar o resultado na sua pergunta?

Comment: Sim so um minuto

Comment: Atualizei minha pergunta

Comment: O estranho é que aparece apenas um item, além do mais ele so aparece quando inspeciono elemento, pois no site mesmo não está o problema,

Comment: você editou e colocou o código da minha pergunta? tem o `data` ele retorna `4 objetos` precisa abrir o que tem dentro! mas, eu to vendo que é uma coisa simples. Poste seu código html dessa pagina?

Comment: Eu atualizei meu codigo, e verifiquei que esta realmente funcionando, porem realemente na hora de iterar os itens não estou tendo exito, penso que o problema seja na hora de somar os itens. Pois a ideia base é pegar o que ja tem dentro da div, e soma com o novo html, e assim ir iterando e no final terei varios itens e apenas coloco na div

Comment: o Somar ali seria concatenar, tem algum problema que por algum motivo anda escondido !!!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46582/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-renan-rodrigues).