# Propriedade do objeto vindo do JSON não está acessivel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Bom estou trabalhando com o `framework Laravel` na `versão 5.2` estou desenvolvendo uma `API` onde tenho um `Painel administrativo` que produz e gerencia o conteúdo, no caso em questão `produto`, e tenho um outro site que consumirá está `API do painel administrativo` onde ela tem que listar todos os produtos.

Dentro de `produto` tenho vários itens como: imagens, categoria, subcategoria, entre outros. Estou consumindo esta `API` via `JQUERY` efetuando o comando `$.getJSON()`. Porém estou tendo problemas para acessar meus itens do produtos como por exemplo imagens.

Em meu `Model produto` fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = [
    'CdSubCategoria',
    'NmProduto',
    'DscProduto',
    'VlUnit',
    'UnitEmEstoque',
    'FlgDescontinuado',
    'FlgProdutoVisivel',
    'Visivel_Ini',
    'Visivel_Fim',
    'FlgPontua',
    'QtdPontos',
    'MaxPontosPorSubCategoria'
];
protected $primaryKey = 'CdProduto';
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function subCategoria()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SubCategoria','CdSubCategoria','CdSubCategoria');
}

public function imagens(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Imagem', 'CdProduto', 'CdProduto');
}

public function lotes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\LoteProduto', 'CdProduto', 'CdProduto');
}

public function tipo_produto_embalagem(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoProdutoEmbalagem', 'CdProduto', 'CdProduto');
}
```

No meu `Controller Produto` que é onde acesso com `$.getJSON()` eu fiz o seguinte, uma função `index()` que identifica o primeiro `metodo` de meu `controller`:

```
public function index(){
    $produtos =  Produto::all();

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return compact('produtos');
    }else{
        return view('Produto.listProduto', compact('produtos'));
    }
}
```

Meu `return compact('produtos')` é o que envia quando faço a `requisição`.

Em meu site estou recebendo este `array` e faço um `.each()` em minha `váriavel` dentro deste `.each()` que estou tentando acessar meus itens do produto como imagens.

Meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
   $.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/produtos', function(data) {
      $('#todosProdutos').html('');
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
            var ANTIGO = $('#todosProdutos').html();
            console.log(item.imagens); //Aqui dei um console para tentar verificar as imagens porém retorna undefined

            var html = ANTIGO + 'MEU HTML';
        });
        //console.log(html);
       // $('#todosProdutos').html(html);
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Em meu `console.log(item.imagens)` está retornando `undefined` em qual parte do processo estou errando ? Tentei acessar outras como categoria, e também não está funcionando.

Quando dou `console.log(item)` ele retorna apenas os itens que realmente estão na mesma tabela de produto, como exemplo: NmProduto, VlUnit, UnitEmEstoque, entre outros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Laravel existe duas formas de carregar o relacionamento: *eager loading constraints* e *lazy loading*.

A primeira, que é *eager loading constraints* (carregamento ansioso, carrega os relacionamentos antecipadamente, antes de acessar os valores dos relacionamentos definidos. Já o segundo, *lazy loading* (carregamento preguiçoso), só acessa quando você chama o relacionamento.

Não é possível usar *lazy loading* para `JSON`. Então, quando se trata de requisições Ajax, eu recomendo sempre usar *eager loading constraints*, pois assim os dados do relacionamento estarão disponíveis sempre.

Essa operação é feita através do método `with`.

Veja:

```
public function index(){
    $produtos =  Produto::with('imagens')->get();

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return compact('produtos');
    }else{
        return view('Produto.listProduto', compact('produtos'));
    }
}
```

Comment: E para acessar em meu html como faço ?

Comment: Hum... Isso não está na pergunta, mas você simplesmente pode fazer `$produto->imagens` dentro do `foreach` com `$produtos`. Se precisar de mais detalhes seria melhor fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: Eu ja fiz, inclusive estou com problemas nisto também olha so http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157691/problema-com-each-jquery

Comment: @RenanRodrigues `$produto->imagens` retorna uma coleção, tem que varrer essa lista. Como o Wallace Maxters citou e você mesmo também disse, seria uma outra pergunta (já foi feita o questionamento)

Comment: Você está falando de html manipulando com jQuery ou com blade? Agora fiquei confuso.

Comment: Ali no caso estou com jquery, pois a ideia é que estarão em servidores diferente, na verdade isto esta meio confuso para mim ainda, porém estou utilizando jquery

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Como vou fazer esta requisição com blade ?  e o blade pecorrer para mim ? Isto não está claro

Comment: @VirgilioNovic essa situação me lembrou sua pergunta no meta. Inclusive eu elaborei uma [resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5384/4995) pra você

Answer (score 1):

Faltou carregar o relacionamento, isso não é automático com foi feito:

Com o comando [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) do [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent), é carregado os relacionamentos:

```
public function index()
{
    $produtos =  Produto::with('imagens')
                         ->get();

    if(Request::wantsJson())
    {
        return compact('produtos');
    }

    return view('Produto.listProduto', compact('produtos'));
}
```

Se por ventura precisar carregar os outros relacionamentos acrescente [`->with('')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) com o nome dos relacionamentos:

***Exemplo:***

```
$produtos =  Produto::with('imagens')
                    ->with('lotes')
                    ->get();
```

ou com um `array`

```
$produtos =  Produto::with(['imagens','lotes'])
                    ->get();
```